# Send onPostExecute() result to Service

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have two classes, MainActivity and SMSMonitorService.

In MainActivity class i implement AsyncTask.

In SMSMonitorService class i have senReplySMS method with two parameters: String number and String responseText.

I want to send the onPostExecute() result as sendReplySMS parameter (responseText).

MainActiviy.class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   /*.
     . Code
     .
   */

   public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    //Extract String between two delimiters.

        String finalResult = StringUtils.substringBetween(result, "extract\":\"", "\"}}}}");            
        String finalResponse = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(finalResult);

        textView.setText(finalResponse);            

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SMSMonitorService.class);
        intent.putExtra("onPostResult", finalResponse);
        startService(intent);            
    }
}
```

SMSMonitorService.class

```
public void sendReplySMS(String number, String responseText) { 

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, responseText, null, null);
}

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    String onPostReceive = intent.getStringExtra("onPostResult");

    sendReplySMS(number, onPostReceive);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The app does not start.

How send the onPostExecute() result string as sendReplySMS method parameter?

Thanks for advance.

EDIT:

Correction: When i press a toggle button for run the service, i get force close.

Logcat:

```
12-30 00:24:33.647  10929-10929/com.textnet.apitest I/MainActivity﹕ SMSMonitor Started
12-30 00:24:33.927  10929-10929/com.textnet.apitest I/SMSMonitorService﹕ SMS Monitor service started
12-30 00:24:33.937  10929-10929/com.textnet.apitest I/SMSMonitorService﹕ Broadcast Receiver  registered 
12-30 00:24:33.977  10929-10929/com.textnet.apitest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with      uncaught exception (group=0x40b099f0)    
12-30 00:24:34.147  10929-10929/com.textnet.apitest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.textnet.apitest.SMSMonitorService@4125e140 with Intent { cmp=com.textnet.apitest/.SMSMonitorService }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2376)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
        at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:88)
        at com.textnet.apitest.SMSMonitorService.sendReplySMS(SMSMonitorService.java:31)
        at com.textnet.apitest.SMSMonitorService.onStartCommand(SMSMonitorService.java:38)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What you are getting in `intent.getStringExtra("onPostResult");`?

Comment: "The app does not start"--what you means??

Comment: The application quits to start. Excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: You means getting force close? If so post the logcat...

Comment: Correction: When i press a toggle button for run the service, i get force close.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining onStartCommand, you should override `onHandleIntent`.

Note that your `SMSMonitorService` must derive from `IntentService` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What i am identifying is you should call stofSelf() after calling SMSManager: You might be getting ANR as Service is completed the task and its running in UI main thread. If UI Main thread got block for more then 5 sec system will fire ANR. Please check and revert back with your observation.

public void sendReplySMS(String number, String responseText) {

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, responseText, null, null);
stopSelf()
```

}

Comment: As per logs shared by you are getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress , You might not be passing correct values for destination address.

Comment: `onStarCommand` is executed to activate the service, in that moment `number` is empty and responseText is empty too, therefore fails. any solution? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number variable in onStartCommand(); once check it properly whether it is initialized or not and if initialized check if it is valid phone number or not

Comment: `public String number="";` I get number from a BroadcastReceiver in SMSMonitorService.

Comment: `onStarCommand` is executed when i activate the service, in that moment `number` is empty and `responseText` is empty too, therefore fails. any solution? Thanks for advance.